# How to Interact with an item of a List in Pygame?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random, pygame

i Started creating a game and ***i stumbled into a little problem***:

*When pressing "SPACE Bar" Red Squares keep Spawning randomly on Display

**Question** 
How can i make the Red Squares into obstacles?

im a total begginer and im sorry for asking such a simple question.. :/

The Code might give you an idea:

```
import pygame, sys
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import*

"List the Stores the Squares"
red_square_list = []

gameDisplay_width = 800
gameDisplay_height = 600

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((gameDisplay_width, gameDisplay_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Square-it")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
red_color = pygame.Color("red")

"White Square"
white_x = 400
white_y = 300
white_width = 10
white_height = 10
white_color = pygame.Color("white")
white = pygame.Rect(white_x, white_y, white_width, white_height)

"Red Squares"
def create_red_square(x, y):
    red_width = 10
    red_height = 10
    red = pygame.Rect(x, y, red_width, red_height)
    return red

while True:

    clock.tick(60)
    gameDisplay.fill((0, 20, 5))
    gameDisplay.fill(white_color, white)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           sys.exit()

    for each in red_square_list:
        gameDisplay.fill(red_color, each)

    pygame.display.update()

    '''White Square Movement'''
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        white.left = white.left - 4

    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        white.right = white.right + 4

    if keys[K_UP]:
        white.top = white.top - 4

    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        white.bottom = white.bottom + 4

    "when Space key Pressed, Spawns red Squares"
    if keys[K_SPACE]:
        x = randint(0, gameDisplay_width)
        y = randint(0, gameDisplay_height)
        red_square_list.append(create_red_square(x, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current system, as long as Space is being held down, a red square will be added to the list. This means that a square will be placed every FRAME the button is being pressed. Too much! What you want to do is add the following into your event loop. This will activate ON the frame that you press the key, not any more than that.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
         x = randint(0, gameDisplay_width)
         y = randint(0, gameDisplay_height)
         red_square_list.append(create_red_square(x, y))
```